# How to dynamically route traffic to a specific instance of a service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I have a service deployed on Fargate which auto-scales, and an internet-facing load balancer directing traffic to that service.

The service relies on an in-memory cache to produce fast responses, and hence auto-scaling is triggered when we start to run low of memory. The contents we need from the cache depends on the request.

If the start situation with a single instance of the service running looks like

```
_______                              ________________
| ELB |  Request for project A ->    | Service with  |
|_____|  Request for project B ->    |__cache________|
```

and the service auto-scales to 2 instances, I would like to end up with

```
_______                              ______________________________
| ELB |  Request for project A ->    | Instance 1 of Service with |
|_____|                              |__cache_____________________|
                                     ______________________________
         Request for project B ->    | Instance 2 of Service with |
                                     |__cache_____________________|
```

That way, `Instance 1` of the service can use its whole in-memory cache for resources related to project A and `Instance 2` of the service its in-memory cache for resources related to project B.

If both instances would receive a mix of requests for projects A and B, their cache would be to small and they would constantly need to dump contents from the cache and loading new contents, defeating the whole purpose of why we triggered auto-scaling in the first place.

The closest thing I found is using [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html) but I don't think that will solve my problem as the first request which creates the cookie might land on the wrong service. Nor would it help if the requests arrived before the service was autoscaled.

Comment: Such things are handled by multiple target groups. Since you have two different services,  you need to target groups.

Comment: @Marcin Perhaps it wasn't clear from the question, but it's the same service. There are just multiple instances running (will edit and clarify). Does your advice still apply in that case ?

Comment: If its same service, then you can't do this. The entire point of ECS service is to have identical and interchangeable tasks. If you need to somehow differentiate between tasks in a single service, you must have two services.

Comment: What Marcin said. These are now different services. Don't introduce local state like that as you have effectively ruled out scaling.